# start postgres 9.4 server from Windows commandline

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to start the postgres erver from the Windows command line but it keeps failing with the same error:

```
2015-04-14 10:25:19 GST LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: No error

2015-04-14 10:25:19 GST HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.

2015-04-14 10:25:19 GST LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: No error

2015-04-14 10:25:19 GST HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.

2015-04-14 10:25:19 GST WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"

2015-04-14 10:25:19 GST FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

I am able to access the server if I try connecting to it from pgAdmin. I do not have any other services running on 5432 since I have checked the Task Manager for apps running on that port.

The command I am using to start is

```
pg_ctl start -D "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\data"
```

but I have also tried

```
postgres -D "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\data"
```

My IPv6 setting are set to dynamic ip while my v4 settings are set to my broadband modem ip. I also disabled Windows Firewall and my antivirus AVG. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that there *is* a service already on that port, but you don't see it in Task Manager because by default it will only show tasks owned by your user.

Check the `netstat` command's output, when run in an Administrator command prompt.

Also look in `services.msc` for a `postgresql-9.4-x86` service that might be running.

Note that in addition to this issue, PostgreSQL should generally be run as a Windows service. Use `pg_ctl register` to create a service if one does not exist.

If you want to run PostgreSQL by hand, I suggest `initdb`ing your own data directory, rather than re-using the one created by the installer. You can otherwise run into problems with file permissions if you switch back to running as a service later.